# Error loading template for Spring Boot using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, thymeleaf

I have a springBoot application which uses Thymeleaf for rendering templates. When I run the application from Eclipse, all works perfectly. However when I try to build the jar and run it, one template refuses to load with the following exception:

> Exception processing template "/XXX/form/importConfiguration": Error
>   resolving template "/XXX/form/importConfiguration", template might not
>   exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template
>   Resolvers

The controller code is quite simple:

```
@Controller
public class ImportConfigurationsController extends BaseController
{
   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImportConfigurationsController.class);

   private static final String PATH_IMPORT_CONFIG = "/XXX/importConfigurations";
   private static final String PATH_INIT_IMPORT_CONFIG = "/XXX/initLoadingXMLConfiguration";
   private static final String PATH_IMPORT_CONFIG_FROM_XML = "/XXX/importConfigurationFromXML";
   private static final String TEMPLATE_IMPORT_CONFIG = "/XXX/form/importConfiguration";

   /**
    * Loads the import configuration page
    * 
    * @param model
    * @return
    * @throws Exception
    */
   @GetMapping(PATH_IMPORT_CONFIG)
   public String importConfiguration(Model model) throws Exception
   {
      log.trace("Enter Method importConfiguration. Params: {}", model);

      log.trace("Return Method importConfiguration.");
      return TEMPLATE_IMPORT_CONFIG;
   }
```

I checked the jar file, and the html file does exist. In addition, all other templates except this one run normally. Anyone can give me hand with this?

EDIT: pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>XXXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXXX</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>

    <properties>
        <jar.filename>XXXX-${version}</jar.filename>

        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <commons.lang3-version>3.1</commons.lang3-version>
        <mybatis-version>3.4.1</mybatis-version>
        <ojdbc-version>11.2.0.4</ojdbc-version>
        <guava-version>19.0</guava-version>
        <commons-configuration-version>1.6</commons-configuration-version>
        <commons-jxpath-version>1.3</commons-jxpath-version>
        <javax-version>2.1</javax-version>

        <project.branch>trunk</project.branch>
        <deploy.dir>${project.basedir}/deploy</deploy.dir>
        <dist.dir>${deploy.dir}/XXXX/${project.branch}</dist.dir>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <finalName>${jar.filename}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Run: runs Ant tasks for Maven -->
                        <id>copy-extra-files</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Ant targets to be executed -->
                            <target name="build-distribution">
                                <echo message="Deleting ${dist.dir} folder" />
                                <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />

                                <echo message="Copying application scripts to ${dist.dir} folder" />
                                <copy todir="${dist.dir}/application">
                                    <fileset dir="scripts" />
                                </copy>

                                <echo message="Copying SQL scripts to ${dist.dir}/sql folder" />
                                <copy todir="${dist.dir}/sql">
                                    <fileset dir="sql" />
                                </copy>

                                <echo message="Copying config to ${dist.dir}/config folder" />
                                <copy todir="${dist.dir}/application/config">
                                    <fileset dir="src/main/resources"
                                        includes="application.properties, messages.properties, log4j2.xml" />
                                </copy>

                                <echo message="Copying application's packaged jar file" />
                                <copy todir="${dist.dir}/application" verbose="true">
                                    <fileset file="target/${jar.filename}.jar" />
                                </copy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-extra-files</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.lang3-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>${ojdbc-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>${mybatis-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-configuration-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-jxpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-jxpath</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-jxpath-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

UPDATE:

There seems to be something wrong with the controller itself. When I tried returning the name of another template in the controller, which loaded perfectly fine in another controller, I got the same exception. So for some reason Thymeleaf doesn't seem to be able to load the templates from this controller.

Comment: Is there a "form" folder inside "XXX" directory? Change package type to war and build again. Then try running this in the tomcat standalone installation.

Comment: Yes, the "form" folder does exist. I think changing the packaging would require major code changes, which I'm not willing to do as of now

Comment: Can you share pom.xml if any?

Comment: You do not need to do any code changes. Just add    <packaging>war</packaging> under <version>1.7</version> in pom.xml

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work. I read at several places online that my main class needs to extend SpringBootServletInitializer to be deployable under tomcat, which would require more changes than I'm willing to do.

Comment: Is there any way to share your code?

Comment: Unfortunately the application I'm working on is proprietary, so I can't share all of the code. However I can provide "commented" code or project structure which might be helpful in diagnosing the issue

Comment: Can you just create a sample project without the business logic and share?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting everybody's time. It turns out, as usual, that there was a stupidly simple reason why I was having the issue. While creating the new controllers, it seems that we oversaw there was a leading "/" in the template path. So instead of the path being "XXX/path/to/file", it was "/XXX/path/to.file".

I'm adding this for the benefit of anyone else who might experience this issue.

In an afterthought, I think this should be highlighted somewhere, as the error message was far from descriptive. A leading "/" should not stop the template from loading, and if so, the error should at least give an indication of what went wrong.